# Why does PeeWee quote table names?

Tags: python-3.x, peewee

I'm trying to integrate PeeWee with SQL Relay and I've run into the issue where PeeWee creates SQL statements with double quotes around table names.

Here's some sample code

```
from peewee import BooleanField
from peewee import CharField
from peewee import DateField
from peewee import ForeignKeyField
from peewee import Model
from SQLRelay import PySQLRDB
from sqlrelay_ext import SQLRelayDatabase

DB = SQLRelayDatabase('test2', host='<hostname>', user='<username>', password='<password>')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()
    is_relative = BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = DB

DB.connect()
Person.create_table(safe=False)
Pet.create_table(safe=False)
```

Here's a sample stack trace.

```
Query: CREATE TABLE "person" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "birthday" DATE NOT NULL, "is_relative" SMALLINT NOT NULL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2576, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/SQLRelay/PySQLRDB.py", line 177, in execute
    raise DatabaseError('<pre>%s</pre>' % the_error)
SQLRelay.PySQLRDB.DatabaseError: <pre>Server message: Incorrect syntax near 'person'. severity(0) number(102) state(1) line(1)  Server Name:ubuntu-mssql  Procedure Name:</pre>
```

While i know this is ANSI standard, it is unfortunately not well supported by many database clients. Is there a specific reason PeeWee does this? Is it possible to create a custom database adapter that could exclude the double quotes?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLRelay is not familiar to me. Peewee quotes table names (and other entities) for a couple reasons:

- It's well-supported by the databases peewee supports out-of-the-box.
- So you can use SQL reserved words as identifiers or aliases
- In the event your table/column contains whitespace (which *has* been reported believe it or not...people do weird stuff).

Without keeping a rather comprehensive list of all SQL reserved words, Peewee won't know when quotes are strictly required versus being optional. This was discussed in a GH issue a while back. I chose not to implement conditional quoting as I didn't want to maintain a special-case plus a big list of reserved words.

You could possibly override the execute_sql() method on your database-class and use a regex to strip all quotes before sending them to the database driver, but that feels a little funky. You could also override the database get_sql_context() method to provide your own SQL-generating context which could possibly also handle de-quoting identifiers.

EDIT: looks like you're using sql server? You could try turning "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes, I am using SQL Server behind SQL Relay. Thanks for the prompt response. I'll try some of those things and report back.

Comment: I decided the easiest route was to override `execute_sql` like you suggested. It isn't the prettiest solution, but it gets me past this stumbling block.